# Semantic UI autocomplete responses arrive out of order

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, semantic-ui

I am using the following Semantic UI autocomplete dropdown:

```
$('.ui.dropdown').dropdown({
    minCharacters: 1,
    apiSettings: {
        url: '/api/people?q={query}'
    }
});
```

It works, except that when I type 'abc' the responses from my server are returned in the order 'abc', 'ab', 'a' and so the final rendered result is the set of suggestions for 'a', while the field contains 'abc'.

Does Semantic UI provide a standard way to deal with this problem or do I need to implement a fix manually?

**Working example showing bug**: https://jsfiddle.net/633h2wdx/ ([screencast](https://youtu.be/44eWOP5Xsx0))

Comment: Please let me know if my answer helpful below

Comment: @SalomonZhang I don't see how that solves the problem (unless I'm missing what you mean)

Comment: any updates on this?

Answer (score 3):

The solution would be to cancel previous request whenever new request is made. Semantic UI provides a flag for this (`interruptRequests`).

```js
$('.ui.dropdown').dropdown({
    minCharacters: 1,
    apiSettings: {
        url: '/api/people?q={query}',
        interruptRequests: true
    }
});
```

Ref: https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/blob/master/RELEASE-NOTES.md

Search for `interruptRequest` in above link.

Comment: Update: this actually doesn't work either. At the moment, it seems you have to manually do this by assigning each request a unique ID.

Comment: lets create a functioning example and then discuss

Comment: retry after passing another flag `throttleFirstRequest: false,`. Seems like it is working as expected with this flag.

Comment: Ok thanks, seems to work with that flag. I imagine this is a reportable bug?

Comment: Yes, it can be reported that `interruptRequests` doesn't work properly when time difference between two requests is very less.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **match** attribute

When using search selection specifies how to match values.

**both**
Matches against text and value

**value**
matches against value only

**text**
matches against text only

The default setting is **both**